# Nginx fails to load static files after I declared them using location

Tags: caching, nginx, gzip, system-administration, server-administration

I've configured Nginx as you can see:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privateKey.key;

    location /webmin/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000;
    }

server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privateKey.key;
    server_name localjob.it;
    access_log off;

    location / {
          alias /webapps/sitoweb/;
    }
```

Now if I go on mysite.com the page is loaded with the CSS, but if I add:

```
    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
          expires 168h;
          add_header Pragma public;
          add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }
```

Now if I go on mysite.com the page can't load CSS.
I can't understand the reason!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx `location`s exclusive so your alias inslide root location doesn't applies to another `location`s. Also it's a bit misuse, just use `root` directive in `server` block.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privateKey.key;
    server_name localjob.it;
    access_log off;

    root /webapps/sitoweb;

    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
          expires 168h;
          add_header Pragma public;
          add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }
}
```

Comment: It work but I've another question. I've added another location like this in the same server declaration:

`location /django/ {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Accept';
}`
Now the all the css in my web site is loaded except the css located in /django/ like www.mysite.com/django/myfile.css